# Autocmd not executing

Tags: vim

I have the following code in my .vimrc.

```
augroup coment_line
   autocmd!
   autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c m'I#<Space><esc>`'
   autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c m'I#<Space><esc>`'
   autocmd FileType vim nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c m'I"<Space><esc>`'
   autocmd FileType css noremap <buffer> <localleader>c m'I/*<space><esc>A<space>*/<esc>`'
augroup END
```

This is supposed to let me easily comment out lines while coding and return my cursor to its original location. My `localleader` is set to `,` so when I'm editing a vim file and I type `,c` I should get `` m'I" <esc>`' ``.

I noticed this wasn't working quite right because instead of my cursor staying in the same place I end up at the end of the line. When I run `:nmap` I see the following

```
n  ,c          *@I" <Esc>$
```

so it looks like `,c` is still being mapped to an old mapping that put the cursor at the end of the line. I have saved and reloaded my .vimrc, and quit and reopened vim many times and I still have the same problem. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: probably mapped by another plugin or ftplugin. [see the faq, especially the second half](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.1)

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. I run `makeview` on loading a each file, and it turned out that somehow the view file hadn't been updated. I deleted it and reopened my file and everything worked.